# jQGrid Toolbar Searching - parameters serverside

Tags: jquery, search, filter, jqgrid, toolbar

im making a jqGrid with a toolbarsearch, and when im posing the data to the server, this is what the posted data looks like

```
_search=true&nd=1431708595575&rows=20&page=1&sidx=invhNumber&sord=desc&invhNumber=00012
```

(formatted)

```
_search:true
nd:1431708595575
rows:20
page:1
sidx:invhNumber
sord:desc
invhNumber:00012
```

the problem is, im filtering for 'invhNumber:00012' but I do not have the comparer (in this case, should be 'eq')

I have a simple grid, and as soon as its completed, i just do

```
$('#mygrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
```

to create the toolbar search.
Also, the filters are empty.
Any thoughts?

from http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching
its written that

> type name:value is posted to the server.

it works as intended, but again, does not say what **comparer** we are applying (equal in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid is old product. One of the first version of `filterToolbar` didn't have the option `searchOperators: true` and the format of the options way `columName=filterValue`. Later it was introduced "Advanced Searching" format of filters (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options)) where all information about the filter was saved in one `filters` parameter. One added `stringResult: true` option to `filterToolbar`, but one hold old format as default to have better compatibility with the old version of jqGrid. Later one added `searchOperators: true` option which have and one sense in combination with `searchOperators: true`, but all defaults stay unchanged.

Thus you have to add `stringResult: true` option to be able to use `searchOperators: true`. I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that the latest version of jqGrid set `stringResult` option to `true` automatically if `searchOperators === true` or if `datatype` of the grid is `"local"`.